# How to get the index range of a list that the values satisfy some criterion in Python?

Tags: python, list

For example, a = [12,11,5,7,2,21,32,13,6,42,1,8,9,0,32,38], I want to find the index range that the value in it is less than 10. Is there a simple way that can return the index range of [[2,4],[8],[10,13]]?

I wrote a function but feel it's tedious:

```
def indexscope(dlist):
    newinterval = True
    scope = []
    for i in range(len(dlist)):
        if dlist[i] < 10:
            if newinterval:
                interval = [i]
                newinterval = False
            else:
                k = i
        else:
            if not newinterval:
                interval[1] = k + 1
                scope.append(interval)
                newinterval = True
    return scope
```

For the mentioned example, I can use indexscope(a) to get my result.

But what if I want to get another index ranges that need the value > 20 for the next time? Ugly wrote another function? **Is there a simple way to get the index range in a general level?**

### Update

1.Yes, as some of you indicated, what I need is the index range. I'll deal with the elements in every index range later. **It's very import for me to keep every continuous element in a same range**.

So, return value of [[2, 4], [8], [10, 13]] and [[2,3,4],[8],[10,11,12,13]] can both be accepted.

2.Currently, @TigerhawkT3's answer can meet my requirement in my example. @DTing's answer catch my further demand. But I'm still finding a more simple way.

### Update2

3.I finally got a two-lines answer refer to @TigerhawkT3's answer and some others in the internet. Now I can give up the function definition and simply replace the criterion for my need. Thank you all for your effort to help me here.

```
l = [idx for idx,value in enumerate(a) if value<10]
print [list(g) for _,g in groupby(l,key=lambda n,c=count():n-next(c))]
```

Comment: It's easy to get valid index using one-line code, but I have no idea how to turn it to index scopes

Comment: Yeah, itertools is useful here. I'm still not clear if it is built-in feature in python, though you can find it in the python document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to @TigerhawkT3's answer, and searched the internet, I got this answer:

```
from itertools import groupby,count
a = [12,11,5,7,2,21,32,13,6,42,1,8,9,0,32,38]
l = [idx for idx,value in enumerate(a) if value<10]
print [list(g) for _,g in groupby(l,key=lambda n,c=count():n-next(c))]
```

It gives list of ranges:

```
[[2, 3, 4], [8], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have your function take a function as an argument to use as the predicate for building your intervals:

```
def indexscope(dlist, predicate):
    scope = []
    start = end = -1
    for i, v in enumerate(dlist):
        if predicate(v):
            if start == -1:
                start = end = i
                continue
            if end + 1 == i:
                end = i
            else:
                scope.append([start] if start == end else [start, end])
                start = end = i
    if start != -1: 
        scope.append([start] if start == end else [start, end])
    return scope

a = [12,11,5,7,2,21,32,13,6,42,1,8,9,0,32,38]

def less_than_10(n):
    return n < 10

print(indexscope(a, less_than_10))
print(indexscope(a, lambda x: x > 20))


[[2, 4], [8], [10, 13]]
[[5, 6], [9], [14, 15]]
```

---

**with scipy:**

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as nd

def passing_ranges(a, predicate):
    return nd.find_objects(nd.label(predicate(a))[0])
```

---

The results are returned as `slice` objects, but that is to your advantage because you can use them to against your original np array:

```
small_a = [12,11,5,7,2,21,32,13,6,42,1,8,9,0,32,38]
small_np_array = np.array(small_a)

valid_ranges = passing_ranges(small_np_array, lambda n: n < 10)

for r in valid_ranges:
    print(r[0], small_np_array[r])

slice(2, 5, None) [5 7 2]
slice(8, 9, None) [6]
slice(10, 14, None) [1 8 9 0]
```

---

**benchmarks**

```
large_a = [12,11,5,7,2,21,32,13,6,42,1,8,9,0,32,38]*1000000
large_np_array = np.array(large_a)

%timeit passing_ranges(large_np_array, lambda x: x < 10)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.2 s per loop

%timeit indexscope(large_a, lambda n: n < 10)
1 loops, best of 3: 6.99 s per loop
```

---

Here is your answer, I even inline the predicate to remove a function call:

```
from itertools import groupby, count

def xibinke(a):
    l = [idx for idx,value in enumerate(a) if value<10]
    return [list(g) for _,g in groupby(l,key=lambda n,c=count():n-next(c))]

%timeit xibinke(large_a)
1 loops, best of 3: 14.6 s per loop
```

Comment: `[8,8]` should be `[8]`

Comment: mhhh... currently, this answer is what I want in a high level. But I'm not sure about the efficiency of the nested function. I supposed there is some built-in function I do not know of numpy or other library can get my result. So define a function is a must?

Comment: The cost of being able to reuse the code will be some function call overhead. This version performs slightly better than precalculating the valid indices and reducing them into ranges. A numpy solution will give you a significant speed increase in speed but not because of the function call overhead. I'll leave you with this: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization.

Comment: @DTing, thank you for your careful work. The benchmarks is very impressive. I learnt a lot from that. The two methods you provide seem faster than mine. But the first one is a little long code and the second is hard to handle for me. The method I found myself can meet my requirement and is rather simple, though it's a little slower. So I voted for your answer but accept myself.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [12,11,5,7,2,21,32,13,6,42,1,8,9,0,32,38]
indices = [idx for idx,val in enumerate(a) if val < 10]
```

This creates a `list` of indices:

```
[2, 3, 4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

I would recommend keeping it that way for easy parsing, but you can also turn it into ranges as follows:

```
ranges = [[]]
for val in indices:
    if not ranges[-1] or ranges[-1][-1] == val-1:
        ranges[-1].append(val)
    else:
        ranges.append([val])
```

This creates a `list` of ranges:

```
[[2, 3, 4], [8], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Now to take out the middle:

```
ranges = [[item[0],item[-1]] if len(item) > 1 else item for item in ranges]
```

Result:

```
[[2, 4], [8], [10, 13]]
```

Comment: It is a little strange that no matching values would return a list with a range (albeit empty). I would expect `[]` to be returned (not `[[]]`).

Comment: You can always check for that with `if not ranges[-1]` at some point after the loop.

Comment: `[10,11,12,13]` should be `[10,13]`

Comment: [10,11,12,13] is OK. But is there more simple way to convert [2,3,4,8,10,11,12,13] to a subset of ranges?

Answer (score 1):

If you are ready to use numpy, To get the index of all elements there is a simple function in numpy library called `numpy.nonzero()` , you have to pass in the condition you want to check.

Example -

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: n = np.array([11,23,4,5,1222,33,6,10])

In [6]: ni = np.nonzero(n < 10)
Out[6]: (array([2, 3, 6]),)

In [7]: ni[0]
Out[7]: array([2, 3, 6])
```

After this, the first element of the return of indices you want.

If you just want the values that meet certain conditions, there is another very simple solution in numpy library that would satisfy your need , the function to use is called - `numpy.where` , please note this would give the values of those, not the index. Example for that -

```
import np
a = [12,11,5,7,2,21,32,13,6,42,1,8,9,0,32,38]
npa = np.array(a)
np.where(a < 10)
>> array([5,7,2,6,1,8,9,0])
```

Comment: still would only give you the indices , not an index scope.

Answer (score 1):

one-line code to get invalid indices, and generate scope by cases

```
# get invalid indices
l = [idx for idx, value in enumerate(dlist) if value<10]

scope = []
for value in l:
    if scope and scope[-1][-1] == value-1:
        scope[-1] = scope[-1][0:1] + [value]
    else:
        scope.append([value])
# scope is exactly what you wanna
```

One-line code with `lambda` function:

```
scope = []
l = [idx for idx, value in enumerate(dlist) if value<10]

# output like [[2, 4], [8], [10, 13]]:
map(lambda x: (len(scope[-1]) == 1 or scope[-1].pop(-1)) and scope[-1].append(
    x) if scope and scope[-1][-1] == x - 1 else scope.append([x]), l)

# output like [[2,3,4],[8],[10,11,12,13]]
map(lambda x: scope[-1].append(x) if scope and 
    scope[-1][-1] == x - 1 else scope.append([x]), l)
```

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 sorry forgot replace `a` with `dlist`, show me the error message if still not working

Comment: For the first one, you've got an `x` in there and I'm not sure what it's supposed to be. The second seems to create a `list` of `[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]` (in Python 2, that is - recreated in Python 3 by wrapping a `list()` call around the `map`).

Comment: @TIgerhawkT3 fixed, you can ignore the `map` result. `scope` is the desire output